# Anchor points were lost while copying and pasting glyphs from one TTF file to another using Font Forge

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, font-design, anchor-point, font-forge

I am copying the glyph from a ttf file of the same emsize 1024 to another ttf file. I get an Anchor lost popup saying that at least one anchor point is lost while copying the glyph. How do I fix this? Will this make any changes to the glyph?[image]